# How to modify content of org-mode document using org-element API?

Tags: org-mode

Let's say I have an `org-mode` file at `~/myorg.org`, looking like this:

```
* TODO My TODO list
** TODO Play games
** TODO Build a boat
** DONE Do something else
```

Now I want to modify this document using `org-element`. Let's say I want to change all TODO items to DONE. I thought something like this would work:

```
(with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect "~/myorg.org") 
  (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'headline
    (lambda (h)
      (org-element-put-property h :todo-keyword "DONE")))
  (save-buffer))
```

The structure returned from `org-element-map` seems fine, but the code doesn't modify the file. Do I have to replace the whole buffer text using `org-element-interpret-data`, or is there some other way?

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/tj64/org-dp. It can do what you are interested in.

Answer (score 7):

The `org-element-put-property` command does not modify the buffer content, it just returns the new element.

I would approach your use case differently: call `save-excursion`, then jump to the top of the buffer (or region, etc). Move forward using `outline-next-heading`. At each heading you can call `org-entry-is-todo-p` and `(org-todo 'done)` to mark each one done. Then save the buffer.

More generally: if you want to use the org-element API to apply changes, I think you are correct that you would need to call `org-element-interpret-data` to convert the updated AST back to text and then replace the buffer content. See http://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html.

Comment: Yes in the specific example that would work. I'm more interested in generally modifying a file's content using the `org-element` API. I'll try to update the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution using `org-map-entries`. If you do `C-c C-c` on the source code block it will change all TODO entries to DONE in the current buffer. One caveat is that if you have `DONE` with `@` (e.g., `"DONE(d@)"`) in `org-todo-keywords`, then the last entry's change will invoke note taking for the change, and I'm not sure how to suppress it. I guess pressing `C-c C-k` once is not too bad.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results none
(let ((MATCH "/+TODO")
      (SCOPE nil)
      (SKIP nil)
      (spacing nil))

  (org-map-entries
   (lambda () 
       (org-todo 'done))
    MATCH SCOPE SKIP))
#+END_SRC

* TODO My TODO list
** TODO Play games
** TODO Build a boat
** DONE Do something else
```